Blazor Fluent UI's FluentDialogProvider Throws (AggregateException_ctor) When Deployed in IIS but Works Fine in Development
I am using the new web app template in .net 8. The dialog service works fine when I am developing in Visual Studio. However, once I deploy to IIS, I get this error in the browser's console.
    at Jn (dotnet.runtime.8.0.4.5vpa91cq8s.js:3:31614)
    at xl (dotnet.runtime.8.0.4.5vpa91cq8s.js:3:182261)
    at 00b217ca:0x1fa8f
    at 00b217ca:0x1bf5a
    at 00b217ca:0xf141
    at 00b217ca:0x1e7a9
    at 00b217ca:0x1ef9f
    at 00b217ca:0xcfbb
    at 00b217ca:0x4412f
    at e.<computed> (dotnet.runtime.8.0.4.5vpa91cq8s.js:3:215333)
callEntryPoint @ blazor.web.js:1
await in callEntryPoint (async)
ei @ blazor.web.js:1
await in ei (async)
Zr @ blazor.web.js:1
startWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
resolveRendererIdForDescriptor @ blazor.web.js:1
determinePendingOperation @ blazor.web.js:1
refreshRootComponents @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
setTimeout (async)
rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh @ blazor.web.js:1
onDocumentUpdated @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1

I have added the provider with interactivity to the MainLayout so

<FluentLayout>
    <FluentHeader>
        INSTA RATE
    </FluentHeader>
    <FluentStack Class="main" Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" Width="100%">
        <NavMenu />
        <FluentBodyContent Class="body-content">
            <div class="content">
                @Body
                <FluentDialogProvider @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly" />
            </div>
        </FluentBodyContent>
    </FluentStack>
    <FluentFooter>
        <div class="link1">
            <a href="https://www.fluentui-blazor.net" target="_blank">Documentation and demos</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link2">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor" target="_blank">About Blazor</a>
        </div>
    </FluentFooter>
</FluentLayout>
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

I have injected and used the IDialogService in my component which is in the client project like so.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using InstaRate.Postgres.Data
@using InstaRate.Postgres.Data.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

@attribute [Authorize]
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
@inject IRepository repository;
@inject IDialogService DialogService



<FluentGrid  Justify="JustifyContent.SpaceBetween">
    <FluentGridItem xs="6" sm="4">
        <FluentCard>
            <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                    <div>Total Reviews</div>
                </FluentStack>
                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Center">
                    <div>
                        <h1>10.0k</h1>
                    </div>
                    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical" VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Top"><p>20%~</p></FluentStack>
                </FluentStack>
               <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                    <div>
                        <p>Growth in reviews for this year</p>
                    </div>
               </FluentStack>
            </FluentStack>
        </FluentCard>
    </FluentGridItem>
    <FluentGridItem xs="6" sm="4">
        <FluentCard >
            <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                    <div><sapn>Average Review</sapn></div>
                </FluentStack>
                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Center">
                    <div>
                        <h2>
                            4.0
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                        <span>Stars go here</span>
                    </FluentStack>
                </FluentStack>
               
                <div><span>Average rating for this year</span></div>
            </FluentStack>
        </FluentCard>
    </FluentGridItem>
    <FluentGridItem xs="6" sm="4">
        <FluentCard>
            <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Center">
                    <FluentIcon Value="@(new Icons.Filled.Size48.AddSquare())" Color="Color.Accent"/>
                    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                        <span>Entity Service</span>
                    </FluentStack>
                </FluentStack>
                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                    <FluentButton Appearance="Appearance.Lightweight" OnClick="@AddReview">Add Review</FluentButton>
                    <FluentButton Appearance="Appearance.Lightweight">Recent</FluentButton>
                    <FluentButton Appearance="Appearance.Lightweight">Highest</FluentButton>
                    <FluentButton Appearance="Appearance.Lightweight">Lowest</FluentButton>
                </FluentStack>
            </FluentStack>
        </FluentCard>
    </FluentGridItem>
       @if (Entity == null)
        {
            <FluentCard>
                Loading...
            </FluentCard>
        }
        else
        {
            @foreach (var item in Entity.Reviews)
            {
                <FluentGridItem  xs="12" md="3" HiddenWhen="GridItemHidden.SmAndDown">
                    <FluentCard Class="custom-card" Style="width: 100%">
                       <FluentGrid Justify="JustifyContent.SpaceBetween" >
                           <FluentGridItem xs="12" md="3">
                                <FluentPersona Name="@item.CreatedBy"
                                               Image=""
                                               ImageSize="50px">
                                </FluentPersona>
                           </FluentGridItem>
                           <FluentGridItem xs="12" md="9">
                            Total Reviews: 14
                           </FluentGridItem>
                       </FluentGrid>
                    </FluentCard>
                </FluentGridItem>
                <FluentGridItem xs="12"  md="9">
                    <FluentCard Class="custom-card" Style="margin: 5px; width: 100%">
                    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                        <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                            <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                                    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (i < item.Rating)
                                        {
                                            <FluentIcon Value="@(new Icons.Filled.Size20.Star())" Color="@Color.Accent" />
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <FluentIcon Value="@(new Icons.Regular.Size20.Star())" />
                                        }
                                    }
                                    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                                        <p>@item.DateCreated</p>
                                    </FluentStack>
                                </FluentStack>
                                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                                    @item.Content
                                </FluentStack>
                                <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">

                                </FluentStack>
                            </FluentStack>
                        </FluentStack>
                    </FluentStack>
                </FluentCard>
                </FluentGridItem>
            }
        }
</FluentGrid>


@code {
    public ServiceEntity Entity { get; set; }
    AddReviewDialog.ReviewContent DialogData { get; set; } = new();

    [Parameter]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    private async Task AddReview()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
        DialogData.ServiceId = Id;
        //var data = new AddReviewDialog.ReviewContent() { Rating = 2, Body = "" };

        IDialogReference dialog = await DialogService.ShowDialogAsync<AddReviewDialog>(DialogData, new DialogParameters()
            {
                Height = "400px",
                Title = "Add Review For Company X",
                PreventDismissOnOverlayClick = true,
                PreventScroll = true,
            });

        var result = await dialog.Result;
        if (!result.Cancelled && result.Data != null)
        {
            DialogData = (AddReviewDialog.ReviewContent)result.Data;
        }

    }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Entity = await repository.GetById(Id);
        if (Entity == null)
        {
            Entity = new ServiceEntity { Reviews = new List<InstaRate.Postgres.Data.Models.Review>() };
        }
        else if (Entity.Reviews == null)
        {
            Entity.Reviews = new List<InstaRate.Postgres.Data.Models.Review>();
        }
    }


}

This is the Dialog
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using InstaRate.Postgres.Data
@implements IDialogContentComponent<AddReviewDialog.ReviewContent>
@inject IRepository repository;
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider;
@inject IDialogService DialogService

<AuthorizeView Context="authContext">
    <FluentDialogHeader ShowDismiss="true">
        <FluentStack VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Center">
            <FluentIcon Value="@(new Icons.Regular.Size24.WindowApps())" />
            <FluentLabel Typo="Typography.PaneHeader">
                @Dialog.Instance.Parameters.Title
            </FluentLabel>
        </FluentStack>
    </FluentDialogHeader>
    <FluentDialogBody>
        <EditForm Model="Model" FormName="add_review">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <div class="review-dialog" style="margin-left: 20px">
                <div>
                    <FluentPersona Name="@authContext.User.Identity?.Name"
                                   Image=""
                                   ImageSize="50px">
                    </FluentPersona>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 70%; display: flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:space-between">
                    @for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                    {
                        int starNumber = i;
                        if (starNumber <= Model.Rating)
                        {
                            <FluentIcon Value="@(new Icons.Filled.Size20.Star())" Color="@Color.Accent" OnClick="() => SetRating(starNumber)" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <FluentIcon Value="@(new Icons.Regular.Size20.Star())" OnClick="() => SetRating(starNumber)" />
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px">
                    <FluentTextArea Name="review_content" Cols="60" @bind-Value=Model.Body Placeholder="Share details of your experience" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="color: var(--error);">
                <FluentValidationSummary />
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    </FluentDialogBody>

    <FluentDialogFooter>
        <FluentButton Appearance="Appearance.Accent"
                      OnClick="@AddReviewAsync">
            Save
        </FluentButton>
        <FluentButton Appearance="Appearance.Neutral"
                      OnClick="@CancelAsync">
            Cancel
        </FluentButton>
    </FluentDialogFooter>
</AuthorizeView>
@code {
    private EditContext _editContext = default!;

    private ReviewContent Model = new();

    [Parameter]
    public ReviewContent Content { get; set; } = default!;

    [CascadingParameter]
    public FluentDialog Dialog { get; set; } = default!;

    private async Task AddReviewAsync()
    {
       
        
            var authState = await authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var review = new InstaRate.Postgres.Data.Models.Review
            {
                Content = Model.Body,
                CreatedBy = authState.User.Identity.Name,
                DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Rating = Model.Rating,
            };

            review.SetRating(Model.Rating);
            await repository.AddReviewAsync(Content.ServiceId, review);
            await DialogService.ShowSuccessAsync("review successfully added");
            await Dialog.CloseAsync(Content);
        
    }

    private async Task CancelAsync()
    {
        await Dialog.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void SetRating(int rating)
    {
        Model.Rating = rating;
    }

    public record ReviewContent
    {
        [MinLength(10)]
        public string Body { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public long ServiceId { get; set; }
    }

}


Check the logs on the server-side to see if there are any specific error messages or exceptions being thrown when the application is deployed on IIS. This can give you more insight into what might be going wrong.

Have you tried running the release version of the applcation from the command line? This may not be an IIS issue.
